# $\binom{n}{r}$ where $r$ can only be chosen in groups of $k$

Tags: combinatorics

I just started my learning in combinatorics, and I know that number of ways to choose $r$ items from $n$ items without order is given by $\binom{n}{r}= \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$. However, I couldn't figure out the number of ways to choose $r$ items from $n$ items, where the $r$ chosen items are restricted such that they can be chosen only in groups less than or equal to $k$ $(k<=r)$ each time.

Perhaps my above description is unclear, so let me try to present it in a more concrete way: on a cartesian plane, in each move you can either go $(+1,0)$ or $(0,+1)$ (move in x or y direction for 1 positive unit), how many valid shortest paths (only walking $n$ steps in total) are there from $(0,0)$ to $(r,n-r)$, if you can only walk in the $x$ direction for at most $k$ consecutive times before changing direction?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "chosen only in groups less than or equal to $k$" means.

Comment: I just realized the title might cause confusion, since it is asking how many ways there are to choose r from n in "exact groups of k" rather than "groups less than or equal to k". However, I would love to know the approach to solving both of these questions, since I think knowing the first question is crucial in solving the second question.

Comment: Could you look at the example I provided. Maybe that does a better job at explaining the question I'm asking

Comment: While I figured out what you mean, it might be clearer if you talked about paths from$(0,0)$ to $(r,n-r)$ with each step being $(0,+1)$ or $(+1,0).$ Now you are talking about the same count.

Comment: Thanks! Edited already

Answer (score 2):

> The number of valid paths of length $n$ consisting of $r$ horizontal $(1,0)$-steps and $n-r$ vertical $(0,1)$-steps with at most $k$ consecutive horizontal steps is
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{q=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{r}{k+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-(k+1)q}{r-(k+1)q}\binom{n-r+1}{q}(-1)^q}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> where the symbol $\left\lfloor\cdot\right\rfloor$ denotes the *[floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)*.
>
> **Example:** Let's look at an example $n=6, r=4, k=2$.
>
> We have a total of $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{6}{4}=15$ paths of length $6$ with four horizontal steps. The restriction $k=2$ gives according to (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{q=0}^{1}\binom{6-3q}{4-3q}\binom{3}{q}(-1)^q&=\binom{6}{4}\binom{3}{0}-\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\\
> &=15-9\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=6}
> \end{align*}
> valid paths. The six valid paths are marked blue in the list below where $a$ encodes a horizontal $(1,0)$-step and $b$ a vertical $(0,1)$-step.
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> \mathrm{aaaabb}\qquad&\qquad \mathrm{abaaab}\qquad&\qquad \mathrm{baaaab}\\
> \mathrm{aaabab}\qquad&\qquad \color{blue}{\mathrm{abaaba}}\qquad&\qquad \mathrm{baaaba}\\
> \mathrm{aaabba}\qquad&\qquad \color{blue}{\mathrm{ababaa}}\qquad&\qquad \color{blue}{\mathrm{baabaa}}\\
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{aabaab}}\qquad&\qquad \mathrm{abbaaa}\qquad&\qquad \mathrm{babaaa}\\
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{aababa}}\qquad&&\qquad \mathrm{bbaaaa}\\
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{aabbaa}}\qquad
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}

The following proof might be somewhat beyond OPs current level. Its just to give an impression how (1) can be shown.

**Proof:** We use generating functions in order to derive (1) and start with generating functions of binary **Smirnov words**. These are words with no equal consecutive characters. In terms of paths these are paths with no equal consecutive steps. (See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.) Encoding $(1,0)$-steps with $x$ and $(0,1)$-steps with $y$ the generating function of Smirnov words is
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{y}{1+y}\right)^{-1}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
The coefficient of $x^ry^{n-r}$ in the generating function above gives all words of length $r+(n-r)=n$ with no runs of $(1,0)$-steps or $(0, 1)$-steps with length $>1$. This is a convenient starter but we need some adaptations. At first we note that the runs of $(0,1)$-steps are not restricted. We therefore substitute occurrences of $(0,1)$-steps with one or more $(0,1)$-steps.
\begin{align*}
y\quad\to\quad y+y^2+y^3+\cdots=\frac{y}{1-y}
\end{align*}
Each of the wanted paths has at most $k$ horizontal $(1,0)$-steps. We respect this by substituting
\begin{align*}
x\quad\to\quad x+x^ 2+\cdots+x^k=\frac{x\left(1-x^k\right)}{1-x}
\end{align*}

We obtain using the generating function (2) and the substitutions above the wanted generating function
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A_k(x,y)}&=\left(1-\frac{\frac{x\left(1-x^k\right)}{1-x}}{1+\frac{x\left(1-x^k\right)}{1-x}}-\frac{\frac{y}{1-y}}{1+\frac{y}{1-y}}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{x\left(1-x^k\right)}{1-x^{k+1}}-y\right)^{-1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-y\,\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}}\,\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

Since we are looking for paths with length $n$ with $r$ $(1,0)$-steps, and $n-r$ $(0,1)$-steps, we are looking for the coefficient of $x^{r}y^{n-r}$ in $A_k(x,y)$.

We obtain denoting with $[x^r]$ the coefficient of $x^r$ in a series the number of valid paths as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[x^{r}y^{n-r}]A_k(x,y)}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

> We start calculating (4) by expanding (3) in powers of $y$. We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{r}}&\color{blue}{y^{n-r}]A_k(x,y)}=[x^{r}y^{n-r}]\frac{1}{1-y\,\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}}\,\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}\\
> &=[x^{r}y^{n-r}]\sum_{q=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}\right)^{q+1}y^q\tag{5.1}\\
> &=[x^r]\left(\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}\right)^{n-r+1}\tag{5.2}\\
> &=[x^r]\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\binom{-(n-r+1)}{q}(-x)^q\left(1-x^{k+1}\right)^{n-r+1}\tag{5.3}\\
> &=[x^r]\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\binom{n-r+q}{q}x^q\left(1-x^{k+1}\right)^{n-r+1}\tag{5.4}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^r\binom{n-r+q}{q}[x^{r-q}]\left(1-x^{k+1}\right)^{n-r+1}\tag{5.5}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^r\binom{n-q}{r-q}[x^{q}]\left(1-x^{k+1}\right)^{n-r+1}\tag{5.6}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{r}{k+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-(k+1)q}{r-(k+1)q}[x^{(k+1)q}]\left(1-x^{k+1}\right)^{n-r+1}\tag{5.7}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{r}{k+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-(k+1)q}{r-(k+1)q}\binom{n-r+1}{q}(-1)^q}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (5.1) we apply the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* expansion.
- In (5.2) we select the coefficient of $y^{n-r}$.
- In (5.3) we apply the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion of $(1-x)^{-(n-r+1)}$.
- In (5.4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (5.5) we apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$. We also set the upper limit of the series to $r$ since other indices do not contribute.
- In (5.6) we note that in the binomial expansion of $\left(1-x^{k+1}\right)^{n-r+1}$ the powers of $x$ are multiples of $k+1$. We respect this by substituting $q\to(k+1)q$ in (5.7) and select finally the coefficient of $x^{(k+1)q}$.